# ancestor gem get tree with ancestor ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, ancestry

Im using the ancestor gem to create a nested menu table.

when I `render json: Menu.all`

I get :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "label": "Menu"
        "created_at": "2018-05-14T14:28:03.883Z",
        "updated_at": "2018-05-14T14:28:03.883Z",
        "ancestry": null
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "label": "Menu 1-1",
        "created_at": "2018-05-14T14:28:13.982Z",
        "updated_at": "2018-05-14T14:28:13.982Z",
        "ancestry": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "label": "Menu 1-1-1",
        "created_at": "2018-05-14T14:28:13.982Z",
        "updated_at": "2018-05-14T14:28:13.982Z",
        "ancestry": "1/2"
    },
 etc
```

What i would like to do is return the id of the parent aswell (I appreciate it is the last figure in the ancestry field but I want it separate.

So I get:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "label": "Menu"
        "created_at": "2018-05-14T14:28:03.883Z",
        "updated_at": "2018-05-14T14:28:03.883Z",
        "ancestry": null,
        "parent_id":null
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "label": "Menu 1-1",
        "created_at": "2018-05-14T14:28:13.982Z",
        "updated_at": "2018-05-14T14:28:13.982Z",
        "ancestry": "1",
        "parent_id":"1"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "label": "Menu 1-1-1",
        "created_at": "2018-05-14T14:28:13.982Z",
        "updated_at": "2018-05-14T14:28:13.982Z",
        "ancestry": "1/2",
        "parent_id":"2"
    },
```

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding `to_json` (https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json) to include `parent_id` in your model class:

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_json
    super(methods: [:parent_id])
  end
end
```

Comment: but parent id is not a column, I need to extract it from the ancestry column or use a method provided by the gem

Comment: You mean, when you call `parent_id` on an instance of `Menu`, you get "undefined method" error?

Comment: As per https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry#navigating-your-tree, i believe you should have the method defined.

Comment: ok I added your code to my model, but still get the same result, do i need to change something in my controller index call?

Comment: if i do this on my controller: @menus = Menu.all.map{|m| m.parent_id} i get all the ids, but only the ids, i dont get the rest of the data..

Comment: Strange! afaik `render json` would call `to_json` method on the object/collection passed to it. Overriding `to_json` in model should work.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i managed to resolve the issue using jbuilder and building the object with that. thanks anyway